# Copy or Move the contents of a range (using Formulas) as Rows to the bottom of another range

Tags: excel, vba, copy, append

I need help. I am working on some automated templates for my company, but I am stumped.

I am trying to move the contents of a range (rows) to the end of another range.

UPDATE:
I removed a lot of my post because I tried to find a work around that would simplify the information needed.

I have 2 sets of columns (Q,R,S) and (AT,AU,AV) starting at Line 7. I wish to copy both sets of data into one column such that; Q,AT into AX, R,AU into AY, and S,AV into AZ).

I tried k1dr0ck's formula and it worked to an extent. Since the cells  in column B:K contained formulas, the copy texts moved to the bottom which was over 1000 rows.

Columns AX,AY,AZ do not contain any information. So I wish to combine both columns from their respective lists and append them into one list.

[Source A, Source B, and their destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0yVI.png)

Comment: Which specific problem did you have getting your attempt to work? Did you come up with some code?

Comment: I am not sure how to create the VBA to get this to work. I may have worded my request strangely, so I apologize. I simply want to copy the contents of a series of rows to the bottom of another list.

Answer (score 0):

Here an attempt for the moment without fully understand the situation.

If have the option to move down the formulas already under the range B:K.  Assuming the actual data (not the heading) start at cell AI7 and there are no other data in the Columns AI:AR.

On row where you going to append the data

@ column B try formula:  `=$AI$7:INDEX($AI:$AK,COUNTA($AI:$AI)+5,3)`

@ column F try formula:  `=$AM$7:INDEX($AM:$AO,COUNTA($AM:$AM)+5,3)`

@ column J try formula:  `=$AQ$7:INDEX($AQ:$AR,COUNTA($AQ:$AQI)+5,3)`

Should work if you’re using 365 version Excel, bit trickier for older versions.

VBA approach by k1dr0ck's answer would be more suitable I believe, even allowing inserting empty rows for appending the data by push existing rows (containing your formulas) down.
Putting the Formula approach in my answer, as I saw the (using Formulas) part in the question's heading.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want a formula try

```
Sub AppendColumns()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row ' find the last row of column Q
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 7 To lastRow ' loop through each row starting at row 7
        Cells(i, "AX").Value = Cells(i, "Q").Value & "--" & Cells(i, "AT").Value
        Cells(i, "AY").Value = Cells(i, "R").Value & "--" & Cells(i, "AU").Value
        Cells(i, "AZ").Value = Cells(i, "S").Value & "--" & Cells(i, "AV").Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you k1dr0ck, this was very close, but it would paste the copied cells over 1000 cells down due to the formulas. I updated the post with new challenge.

Comment: @Sigmas try updated code